# Issue with the ActionBar of the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, navigation-drawer

I am facing the problem with the ActionBar in the Fragment when scrolling. It is taking some extra spaces from the top and the text which is in the top of the screen is getting overlapped. I am confused where is the issue and got stuck here for alonger time. Can you guys help me out to get rid of these problem.

**activity_home.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/tab_selected"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutLinear"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:background="@color/tab_selected"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <com.traveller.widget.TextViewOsaka
                        android:id="@+id/tvHeaderTitle"

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_30dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_box__offwhite"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/scale_10dp">


                        <AutoCompleteTextView

                            android:id="@+id/edSearch"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:hint="Search for an outlet, location or category"
                            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                            android:completionThreshold="1"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/light_grey"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />


                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/tab_selected"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                    app:titleMarginTop="13dp">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frame_home"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/tab_selected"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <com.traveller.widget.TextViewOsaka
                            android:id="@+id/tvCurrentTemp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_weather"
                            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spnCountry"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_box__onwhite"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivBack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_header" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.traveller.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But when working with the activities there is no issues.

Thanks

[image: Screenshot.jpg]

[image: Screenshot2.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue 
i solved it by adding action bar height as margin-top in the fragment holder

```
 <fragment
    android:marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.traveller.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: I am getting the same result by specifying android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: I have attached another screenshot of the page